# Dúvida sobre include em arquivos em diretórios anteriores

Tags: php, include

Digamos que eu tenha um arquivo chamado header.php localizado em CMS/admin/includes. Digamos que eu dei include nesse arquivo header.php em um arquivo chamado index.php localizado em CMS/admin.

Dentro do arquivo header.php eu quero dar include em um arquivo chamado functions.php que fica em CMS/admin (o mesmo diretório que o index.php). Eu deveria usar:

```
<?php include "../functions.php" ?>
```

ou só

```
<?php include "functions.php" ?>
```

pois como o header.php está sendo incluído em um arquivo (index.php) que se encontra no mesmo diretório de functions.php (CMS/admin), eu deveria dar include como se o functions.php estivesse no mesmo diretório de header.php?

Deu pra entender?

Comment: Se voce utilizara o index.php, os outros includes, devem se referenciar a localização do index. Entende? tipo se o arquivo que é o principal e receberá os demais arquivos, ele se tornará um só. Então deve se refenciar a partir da localizaçao do mesmo

Comment: Dependendo do caso é melhor pegar um ponto fixo de partida e concatenar, como o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'restodocaminho'` se tiver muita variação de profundidade. Ou então, configurar o caminho de includes do PHP para uma pasta padrão. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path . Idealmente compensa organizar de maneira a não depender de nada disso.

Answer (score 0):

O diretório corrente do primeiro, o index.php, é assumido em todos os outros arquivos.

Pode usar somente `<?php include "functions.php" ?>`.

Contudo, esteja ciente sobre a diretiva de configuração `include_path`.

Para saber o que contém nessa diretiva, pode invocar a função `ini_get()`.

`echo ini_get('include_path');`

É importante saber disso pois se acontecer um imprevisto, um acidente e tiver outro arquivo "functions.php" num outro diretório que esteja no "include_path", poderá carregar um arquivo inesperado.

É mais seguro adotar o uso de paths absolutos.